# Caching Query Results per user

Tags: mysql, performance, security

I have a system (develop by someone else) where all registered user can query data (similar to data.stackexchange.com). The system is getting big and more user query the system and during the high traffic time the database is slow and I am afraid of security now.

1. What can I do to make the system more secure?
2. What can I do to make the queries faster to execute?

I have a very basic knowledge of mysql and databases and I want to learn. Can you point where I need to look and what can I do? (I would like to build my self, so please no code)

Answer (score 7):

Well, you have two large jobs to do :)

1. How to make the system more secure?  Well, use SSL where you need to.  If the data is not important you can get away without it.  That said, if you want to ultra-secure your logins, then insist on HTTPS.  Above that, ensure that you never compare passwords directly, rather you compare the hashes of the passwords (with the inclusion of a salt).  Additionally, if your website allows people to be remembered, use a token-based approach.  This allows you to assign a unique cookie ID with the client for a period of time that it is valid.  It's not fool-proof, but better than nothing.  Paired with your SSL login requirements, it will be pretty good.
2. Have a look at cache managers.  But before you do, have a gander at what is taking the most time.  What particular pages are hitting your website the hardest?  Once you ascertain that you can come up with a caching strategy which is, unfortunately, completely website-dependant.  What works for one site, would be inadmissable for you.  You can use some kind of memcache to store the common stuff so that the basic "Front page" and "Portal" queries are cached efficiently.  The rest will have to be dealt with in the regular way.

Comment: HTTPS does not protect against SQL Injections. Why not cache results in tables?

Comment: you can look for "sql injection" and "cache mysql results" on stackvoerflow